# Fragment with ViewPager setCustomAnimations not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have FragmentTransactions working perfectly well for all other Fragments but when moving to a Fragment that only contains a ViewPager, the animation is not displayed and the new fragment suddenly appears. When tapping the back button, it correctly leaves and the previous fragment enters. Is it because I am using a ViewPager that this happens?

MainActivity:

```
fm.beginTransaction()
     .setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right, android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right)
     .hide(itineraryFragmentReturn)
     .add(R.id.fragment_container, emailFragment, "email_fragment")
     .addToBackStack(null)
     .commit();
```

emailFragment.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:orientation="vertical">

    <CustomViews.VerticalViewPager
        android:id="@+id/verticalViewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </CustomViews.VerticalViewPager>

</FrameLayout>
```

EmailFragment.class:

```
public class EmailFragment extends Fragment
{
    private static final int NUM_PAGES = 2;
    private ViewPager mPager;
    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
    private List<Fragment> fragments;
    private View thisView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.email_fragment, container, false);

        thisView = view;

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        loadAdapter();
    }

    private void loadAdapter()
    {
        fragments = new ArrayList<>();

        mPager = (ViewPager) thisView.findViewById(R.id.verticalViewPager);

        fragments.add(new LocationsFragment());
        fragments.add(new AskEmailFragment());

        //getChildFragmentManager() very important for ViewPager
        mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePageAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), fragments);
        mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
        mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
        mPager.setCurrentItem(1);
    }


    private class ScreenSlidePageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
    {
        private List<Fragment> fragments;

        public ScreenSlidePageAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, List<Fragment> fragments)
        {
            super(fragmentManager);
            this.fragments = fragments;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount()
        {
            return NUM_PAGES;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position)
        {
            return this.fragments.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried commenting out the line `mPager.setCurrentItem(1);` in case that was causing the lack of animation but it wasn't.

Ideally what I would like to do is to display the `Fragment` using custom animations containing a progress bar to begin with, and load the `ViewPager` in the background and then display it. I can easily display a `ProgressBar` but how would I programmatically attach the `ViewPager`, I would assume it is initialised in onCreate before the view is shown?